# Chart is not copying correctly from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Using data from Access, I have created a line chart in Excel.  When I go to copy/paste the chart into a report my DB, the image is not the same.  But, if I paste the same image into a work doc or outlook email, it looks fine.  The same distorted version appears if I paste it into msPaint.  Please see the attached screenshots of the charts.  The big issue is the x-axis labels.  Here is my copy/paste code.

```
Dim objChart As Chart    
objChart.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap, xlScreen
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptDeptWindowChart", View:=acViewDesign

ctlC = Reports!rptDeptWindowChart.Controls.Count

Do
    For Each ctl In Reports!rptDeptWindowChart
        ctl.Name = "ctlDelPic"
        DeleteReportControl "rptDeptWindowChart", "ctlDelPic"
    Next

ctlC = Reports!rptDeptWindowChart.Controls.Count
    
Loop Until ctlC = 0

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste
```

[image: Original Excel Chart]

[image: Image after being pasted into Access]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access is not well-known for it's charting capabilities.  If I were you, I'd stick to using Access for managing large data sets, and export final results of queries to Excel, and do your charting/plotting/graphing in Excel.  Word is great for creating documents, PowerPoint is great for presentations, etc.  You need to use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: That is what I did.  The issue was bringing the bitmap image of the Excel chart back into an access report without it being distorted.